# Circular formula error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have tried to create a formula that will find the last value in a column and aggregate it with the value of another column. But, excel does give me a circular error. Can you explain why I get this error and maybe a solution for it, thanks.

The formula is placed multiple times in the M column within the range of M6:M400 and it looks like this:

```
=INDEX(M$1:M$400;SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A$6:A13="Arbejdsdag")*(ROW(A$6:A13)))))+L10
```

**Use case**
I have a sheet like the image below. Note the M column. Here I am keeping a total sum of the balance for hour registrations. It does work as it is. However, the values between the green lines shouldn't be there as the green lines are the toteal of a day and the white lines are the tasks of the day. Therfore, the balance should only be present on the day, the green line.

The current value of M10 is: =IF(COUNTBLANK(L10)>0;M9;M9+L10)

[image]

Comment: Could you add some sample data or a screenshot, so I can understand what your problem is better, rather than the attempted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are using is referencing the column that the formula is in. This means that it can't get a value, as you're trying to get a value from a cell that will change once it has a value. Once that value changes, it may recalculate be a different value, and so on.

Effectively you're trying to get all the values of column M in this calculation, but *this calculation* is one of the values, so it can't be included until it's calculated, but it can't calculate.

If you can confirm exactly what you need the formula to do, I can edit this to attempt to assist you, but currently I don't fully understand your requirement for this formula. It sounds like you want to get the last cell in column M with data in it (Maybe the cell before the cell you're putting the formula into...?) and add it to another cell?

Comment: While trying to explain the problem to you, I actually found the solution. I used the formula: ´=IF(COUNTBLANK(L10)>0;"";INDEX(M$1:M9;SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A$6:A9="Arbejdsdag")*(ROW(A$6:A9)))))+L10)´