# Ignore empty cells in graph doesn't affect the layout of the graph

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have just got an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1045230/circular-formula-error-in-excel), and now I have a new one.

Before I made the changes in the other question I had a graph that visualised the values in column M without going to the value 0 for every task in my sheet. Now, for every line in my sheet that doesn't contains anything but "". It prints the value as 0. I have tried to set the option: "Show empty cells as:" to "Connect data points with line". But it didn't change anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The option you mention *should* be the one to fix that. What type of chart are you using?

Comment: @Jonno It is a default line chart.

Comment: @Jonno Ups, forgot to mention that the dates are on the x-axis. I have updated the question.

Comment: Try to use pivot chart, you can setup the same chart as you had before and can filter out rows which are empty in "balance" column

Comment: If you make empty cells NA() instead of blank or null, they should be ignored.

Comment: @fixer1234 It does work to use NA(). However, then #N/A is printed in all the cells.